# Redirect custom contract forms to the original form page

Tags: controllers, contact-us, contact-form

I have a custom contact-us form that is a CMS pages.
After submitting the contact form I want to redirect back to the CMS page with the custom contact form.

I need to edit the controller (`app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`) and change the `$this->_redirect('*/*/');` lines.

And I also found out that I need to edit the contact form .phtml file (`app/design/frontend/theme/theme/contacts/form.phtml`) with:

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
</div>
```

To

```
<?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
```

But I do not want to edit the core file. So I want to override the default contact controller.
Therefore I found this [URL](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/).

But I do not know where I need to create the `config.xml` and what code I what code I need inside my custom `IndexController.php` file to achieve what I want.

What do I exactly need to do, to achieve this?

Comment: why you does not rewrite IndexController?

Comment: @AmitBera Where and how do you mean to rewrite IndexController?

Comment: How you have call this contact us on cms?As a idea use http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70475/override-contacts-form-in-magento/70484#70484

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks for the URL. But where do I need to place the config.xml file? I use this to call the contact form: <reference name="content">
  <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/offerte.phtml">
    <action method="setFormAction"><value>/contacts/index/post</value></action>
    <block type="studioforty9_recaptcha/explicit" name="studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit" template="studioforty9/recaptcha/explicit.phtml">
      <action method="setAllow"><value>true</value></action>
    </block>
  </block>
</reference>