# Contact from on CMS page, trouble getting error/success to show

Tags: layout, cms, contact-us

we have a contact form on a CMS page an inserted this through cms block in backend (reason is: we can show some faq info and other above the form).

The first problem was when we submit we are sent to another page. This was solved by adding `$this->_redirectReferer();` in case of error to controller.

Only problem we see now: onError submission the customer is redirected to the current page

- but all form fields are blank: can we pre populate thema again?
- The error global message will not show anywhere (we are a contacts form on a CMS page - I am finding it hard to really add the error information)

Help appreciated

[image]

Comment: what error you got

Comment: no error ..... the error is that we are not seeing either success or error message after form submittal

Comment: i can't understand you got sucess message or not

Answer (score 0):

> The error global message will not show anywhere (we are a contacts form on a CMS page - I am finding it hard to really add the error information)

This was fixed by removing [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83016/redirect-custom-contract-forms-to-the-original-form-page) again `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages`